# A basic problem on sup and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$. Now, can we find an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ $\sup (f_n - f) < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. How to choose such an $N$ ?

Comment: You cannot compute exact value of $N$ without the information about $f_{n}$ and $f$.

Comment: Rolled back to the version the answer below addresses. OP: No change of the question after answers are posted, please.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, we know that for some $N'$ we have that for all $x$ in the domain and $n >N'$,
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
$\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $f_n -f$, so the least upper bound must also be less than $\epsilon$. Thus, whatever $N$ provides uniform convergence at level $\epsilon$ will work for the least upper bound.
$$N = N'$$

Comment: what about now ? i changed the problem definition.

Comment: It's not very good form to change the question so substantially--this needed a completely different proof. Next time, maybe post a new question, since you quite literally had a new question.

Comment: Ok, rolled back as well